# Flink Event Time Window is not triggering

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I am working with apache flink v1.4 and we want to fire our window using event time.

I have made sure that:

1. Time Characteristic have been set
   `env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);` is present
2. I am assigning the watermarks using following code

```
deviceVnetSource.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<DataEngineMessage<String, DeviceVnet>>forMonotonousTimestamps().withTimestampAssigner((event,timestamp)-> event.getValue().getTsSec() * 1000))
```

3. Time Value is in milliseconds
4. In the Sink Function I see following output when events are passed (my watermark time is increasing)
5. ```
   TestSinkFunction - watermark time - -9223372036854775808

   TestSinkFunction - watermark time - 1674113291999 

   TestSinkFunction - watermark time - 1674113292999 

   TestSinkFunction - watermark time - 1674113301999 

   TestSinkFunction - watermark time - 1674113319999
   ```

But My Window function is not triggering which is set to 2 seconds.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

This is how entire pipeline looks like -

```
public class FlinkJob { 
  @Autowired
   StreamExecutionEnvironment env;

 private void runJob() throws Exception {
   env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
  
 var deviceVnetSource = 
  streamClient.streamFromTopic(Constants.DEVICEVNET_SOURCE_TOPIC, 
    "DeviceVnet Source");
   
 var unifiedDistanceStream =      
  deviceVnetSource.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy. 
<DataEngineMessage<String, DeviceVnet>>forMonotonousTimestamps()
            .withTimestampAssigner((event,timestamp)-> 
     event.getValue().getTsSec() * 1000))
            //.keyBy(key -> key.getKey())
            //.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1))) This window is not triggering at all
            //.process(new UnifiedDistanceOperatorTest())
            .addSink(new TestSinkFunction());
}
}
```

Comment: Can You provide some code for Your Pipeline ?

Comment: @dominik-wosiński i have added the pipeline code.

Comment: What happens if You uncomment `keyBy` and try to check if then the watermark is increasing?

Comment: @DominikWosiński it worked once i uncommented key by as well as window part. Thing which helped was adding this line - `env.setParallism(1)` but same code base is not working if i introduce a mapping operation on `deviceVnetSource` stream and get a mapped stream and then apply watermarking.

Comment: `env.setParallelism(1)` suggests the anser here, some of the partitions do not have data flowing through it and they are causing the watermark to stay without change.